# How to convert multiple PDF to Html webpage

Tags: acrobat

I need to convert 800+pdf files into html webpage, and every pdf file had own page on html webpage.
I tried to make with Adobe Acrobat, but what i get was every pdf merged in one big list.

So is there any way to automatically do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use pdftohtml on Linux and make it loop through all the files in the directory.

You can also find more information about pdftohtml on this thread: [How to convert PDF to HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370014/how-to-convert-pdf-to-html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**pdf2htmlEX**

Preserves formatting of the PDF file

[Only works through docker](https://github.com/RonyMacfly/pdf2htmlEX) (On new builds of Linux, this package is not present and deb packages are not installed)

```
sudo docker pull bwits/pdf2htmlex

sudo docker run -ti --rm -v /home/user/Documents/pdfToHtml:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 file.pdf
```